# Data Binding in a WinUI 3 Application

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, winui-3

Please tell me why the binding of the WorkGrid dimensions to the Image dimensions does not work. I'm new to data binding and maybe I'm doing something wrong

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      x:Class="MyProject.MyPage"
      x:Name="_MyPage">
    <Grid x:Name="_MainGrid">
        <Image x:Name="_Image"/>
        <Grid x:Name="_WorkGrid" Width="{Binding ElementName=_Image, Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, TargetNullValue=100}" Height="{Binding ElementName=_Image, Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, TargetNullValue=100}">
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding, Yes thanks a lot. I'm just now using the same method, but I thought that with the binding it would be somehow more aesthetically pleasing. But it turned out to be impossible.